# upgrading console emacs (/usr/bin/emacs) on Mac

Tags: macos, emacs, console

I extensively use `/usr/bin/emacs` in Terminal.

I have Emacs 22 and I'd like to upgrade it to 23. I wonder how to do it.
Googling "emacs download mac" gives me `Emacs.app` which has its own window and user interface, but I don't want that.

I am not sure how I have /usr/bin/emacs in the first place, maybe it came with Mac OS?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can run the Emacs.app version in a terminal like this:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw
```

In my .cshrc file, I use an alias to make this easier to invoke:

```
alias enw '/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw'
```

Comment: On my Macbook, I had to do `nano ~/.bash_profile` and then add `alias enw='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw'`. The `=` is missing in the example above.

Answer (score 8):

It is a standard editor included with OS X and a lot of other *nix systems along with vi/vim, and pico. Personally i wouldnt upgrade the pre-installed one. I would install from Macports, Fink, or Homebrew or compile from source myself to a different location (like `/usr/local`).

Answer (score 3):

Install emacs from [macports](http://www.macports.org/).

```
% sudo port install emacs
```

Then launch it from the terminal

Answer (score 2):

Or you can install `Emacs.app`, follow the instructions [here](http://dropsafe.crypticide.com/article/4955) to create a `~/bin/emacs` script and then launch as `emacs -nw` or any other options.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was on this same search and ended up installing with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) so I could get the latest version along with several libraries, as described in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/274/13005) at the [Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) site:

> Nowadays, I use just GNU Emacs snapshot builds. These have reasonably good OS X support, and are by far the easiest to install, and best supported by the community.
>
> I used to get them from Emacs for Mac OS X, but now I use Homebrew, because it supports more libraries, notably GNU TLS for encrypted network connections.
>
> All in all: Use `brew install emacs --HEAD --use-git-head --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-rsvg --with-imagemagick` :).

(Note that GNU Emacs is what comes preinstalled on Mac OS X, at least on mine as of 10.10.5)

This added a new Emacs binary at `/usr/local/bin/emacs`, leaving the existing installation and `/usr/bin/emacs` in place.

Answer (score 0):

I created a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` pointing to the new version of emacs which was in `Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/`

Answer (score 0):

For those who installed `Emacs` from source (or any other way that doesn't overwrite command line called `emacs`) and want to use this version in the command line, I suggest one of these two approaches:

1. `ln -s ~/path/to/cloned/emacs/src/emacs /usr/local/bin/emacs`

- make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH` and located before `/usr/bin`, by executing `echo $PATH`
- if it is not, add line `export $PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to the file `~/.bash_profile`, then refresh `$PATH` by executing in the terminal `source ~/.bash_profile`

2. add `~/path/to/cloned/emacs/src` to your `$PATH`.

- for example, add line `export $PATH=~/path/to/cloned/emacs/src:$PATH` to the file `~/.bash_profile`, then refresh `$PATH` by executing in the terminal `source ~/.bash_profile`

And yes, MacOS is shipped with many packages pre-installed. But, unfortunately, usually with outdated ones and no *official* package manager to easily upgrade those libraries. That's actually why we have `Homebrew`, `Macports`, maybe others: they serve us as MacOS package managers.